# An error was found while testing the game on Google PLay. ' java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play

Stack Tracing
`java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present`
Everything was done on Unity
I'll copy it here in case you need it.

```
Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present at
j$.util.Optional.get (Optional.java:148)   at 
com.google.android.apps.search.googleapp.accounts.ui.i$a.b (PG:5)   at 
com.google.apps.tiktok.dataservice.df.h (PG:20)   at 
com.google.apps.tiktok.dataservice.df.a (PG:2)   at 
com.google.apps.tiktok.dataservice.cz.run (PG:19)   at 
com.google.apps.tiktok.concurrent.ag.run (PG:6)   at 
com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.dn.run (PG:2)   at 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:462)   
at com.google.common.w.a.dv.a (PG:1)   at com.google.common.w.a.cr.run 
(PG:4)   at com.google.common.w.a.dw.run (PG:1)   at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)   at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)   at 
android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)   at android.os.Looper.loop 
(Looper.java:288)   at android.app.ActivityThread.main 
(ActivityThread.java:7839)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke   at 
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(RuntimeInit.java:548)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main 
(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same exact error. It turned out that the automated tests were clicking an exit button I had that quit the application and the tests thought that my application was crashing. I'm not sure if that is exactly what is happening for you but taking the below steps helped me figure out the issue

- Go to Pre Launch Report --> Overview
- Click the view details arrow in the Report History failing artifact row
- Under the Stability section click view details
- Click show more and scroll down to the section that shows the devices that crashed. Click the view details arrow
- A video should show up of the automated test with the test click locations highlighted
- Observe the last few clicks of the video for any hints on what can be causing the crash

For me I noticed one of the last clicks done was located near my exit button. So I removed the exit button from my next release and the next release passed.