# Will a stability crash on one device in the google play pre launch report prevent me from being able to move my app to production?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I am trying to release my first app that I created using Unity 2021. I had a few private releases of the app sent to google and was passing all tests with my first releases.

In a recent release I added the Advertisement Legacy unity package to my app to include advertisements in my game. Since that release and another where I tried to fix the error, I now get the below stability Crash error on 1 device (google Pixel 6 Android 12 (SDK 31)).

```
Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
  at j$.util.Optional.get (Optional.java:148)
  at com.google.android.apps.search.googleapp.accounts.ui.i$a.b (PG:5)
  at com.google.apps.tiktok.dataservice.df.h (PG:20)
  at com.google.apps.tiktok.dataservice.df.a (PG:2)
  at com.google.apps.tiktok.dataservice.cz.run (PG:19)
  at com.google.apps.tiktok.concurrent.ag.run (PG:6)
  at com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.dn.run (PG:2)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:462)
  at com.google.common.w.a.dv.a (PG:1)
  at com.google.common.w.a.cr.run (PG:4)
  at com.google.common.w.a.dw.run (PG:1)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7839)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

This error does not happen in the unity editor or on my personal phone so I am having difficulty fixing it. I found a recent stack overflow question on the exact same error posting about 3 weeks ago with no responses to it yet ([An error was found while testing the game on Google PLay. ' java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78115151/an-error-was-found-while-testing-the-game-on-google-play-java-util-nosuchelem))

Besides this issue, my app is ready to go into closed testing. I would like to move to that phase and continue trying to fix the issue while the app is being tested. But before I start asking users to test my game, I was wondering if anyone knows whether worst case scenario google will prevent me from moving my app to production because of a crash on one device that they found?